# Tree Traversal - Append node to adjacency matrix after runtime

Tags: java, algorithm, swing, breadth-first-search

I'm building a Tree traversal program which allows users to run BFS and DFS traversals, as well as add and remove nodes.

What I'm stuck on is adding nodes due to problems expanding the adjacency matrix. For this example, I'd like to add a new child node `X` to parent `H`:

[image]

For now, I've hard coded the node `X`, but will allow for custom input later.

User clicks `Add Node` button:

```
    //try and create and connect node via button
AddButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {   
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {   
            Nodes nX = new Nodes("X", nodeX, nodeY, nodeWidth, nodeHeight);
            appendNode(rootNode, nX);
        }
   });
```

Which calls appendNode(): This function is supposed to be creating a new adjacency matrix with the updated size (given the additional node `X`)... copying the data from the old matrix `adjMatrix`, then adding an additional slot for th new node `X`.

```
public void appendNode(Nodes parent, Nodes child) {
    //add new node X to nodeList
    addNode(child);

    //loop through all nodes again to be connected, plus new one... then create new adjMatrix
    int newSize = nodeList.size();

    //make a new adj matrix of the new size...
    int[][] adjMatrixCopy = new int[newSize][newSize];

    int fromNode = nodeList.indexOf(parent);
    int toNode = nodeList.indexOf(child);

    //copy adjMatrix data to new matrix...
    for (int i = 0; i < adjMatrix.length; i++) {    
        for (int j = 0; j < adjMatrix[i].length; j++) {
            adjMatrixCopy[i][j] = adjMatrix[i][j];
        }
    }
    for (int col = 0; col < newSize; col++) {
        adjMatrixCopy[newSize][col] = 1;
    }
//  still need to add newly added node 

//  adjMatrixCopy[fromNode][toNode] = 1;
//  adjMatrixCopy[toNode][fromNode] = 0;
//  adjMatrix = null;
}
```

When I click `appendNode`, it throws this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 12
    at Graph.appendNode(Graph.java:306)
    at Graph$3.actionPerformed(Graph.java:141)
```

Comment: Since you need the overhead for dynamically changing the array size anyway, have you considered using ArrayList instead of actual arrays? It has extremely well tested, working code for changing the size.

Answer (score 1):

```
 adjMatrixCopy[newSize][col] = 1;
```

This is wrong. Maybe you want

```
 adjMatrixCopy[newSize - 1][col] = 1;
```

instead?

Comment: This fixed the error, but the new node `X` is not being appended... the graph is not changing

Comment: Actually I don't quite get your logic here, why setting them all to 1? Also, isn't the adding new node part commented out?

Comment: I dont want to set them all to 1... I just want to set the parent-child connection to 1 (in this case, `rootNode` to `X`)

Comment: Okay, I removed the loop setting them all to one... oops. So it's adding `X` to the Adjacency matrix, but it's not adding the node to the tree on the left

Comment: @Growler Do you need to add it to `nodeList` also? Can't see that anywhere in your code.

Comment: Yes, `addNode(child);` adds the child to the nodeList.